# split list into atomic character vectors by name

Tags: r

Such a simple question that I am probably just failing at googling an easy answer.

I have a list of named character vectors. I would like to turn each element in the list into a character vector by the name of the list item. Toy example:

```
    #// input
    groups <- list(letters = c("a", "b", "c"),
                names = c("peter", "paul"))
    groups
    #> $letters
    #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
    #> 
    #> $names
    #> [1] "peter" "paul"

    #// stuff I don't want to do manually
    letters <- groups[[1]]
    names <- groups[[2]]

    #// desired output
    letters
    #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
    names
    #> [1] "peter" "paul"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Do you need `list2env(groups, .GlobalEnv)` ?

Comment: I surely do need that. Thank you! And NO WONDER I didn't find that via Google. :D Please post as answer so I can close the question.

Comment: may be just `attach(groups)`

Comment: Akrun, that''s a really neat and clean idea. But since I may muck around with those variables I'd rather seem them in the global environment, rather than just having access to them via a search path.

Comment: very interesting! please self answer if @markus does not answer